# Fetch array value - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Consider that i have the following html

```
<input type="text" id="other_floor_plans" name="other_floor_plans[]" value="["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]">
```

To fetch the values i use

```
a = $('#other_floor_plans').val()
```

It returns the following

```
"["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]"
```

If i use a[0], it returns "[" as output. I need to get "Pool" as the first value.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your value is a type of `string` which has a correct `JSON` syntax. Just parse with `JSON.parse` into the array and use your syntax.

```js
const value = '["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]';
const array = JSON.parse(value);

console.log(array[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change little bit of your code specially in markup.

changed your input markup into this `<input type="text" id="other_floor_plans" name="other_floor_plans[]" value='["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]'>`

then get value by jQuery

```
var a = $('#other_floor_plans').val(),
a = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(a[0]);
```

you need to use JSON.parse because you get json formate value and need to be parsed.

for my recommendation you just comma separate value like

```
<input type="text" id="other_floor_plans" name="other_floor_plans[]" value="Pool, Office, Sprinkler, Boiler">
```

then get first value by jQuery

```
var a = $('#other_floor_plans').val().split(",");
console.log(a[0]);
```

This one is much more readable and easy I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval` function to convert string to array and get the value.

```
var a = "['Pool','Office','Sprinkler','Boiler']"; // or you can also assign like this var a ='["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]' 
var firstItem = eval(a)[0];
console.log(firstItem);  //output will be "Pool"
```

Answer (score 0):

There you doing a wrong practice when you initialize value in input box you must contain a value in different quotation symbols.
there you take " for value assign and " also for array string, that truncate your string on the second " that's why this return only [ in your value.
**Try to use like this:**

> HTML

```
<input type="text" id="other_floor_plans" name="other_floor_plans[]" value='["Pool","Office","Sprinkler","Boiler"]'>
```

> JQuery

```
var a = $('#other_floor_plans').val();
a = JSON.parse(a);
console.log(a);
```